# Passing arguments in CMake's build tool mode

Tags: build, cmake

I have a set of small C programs to be compiled with `Nmake`. I launch the build process with

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..

cmake --build buildDir
```

and `Nmake` begins to compile . The problem is that the build process stops at the first compile error. I want to build all programs that could be compiled. I know that there `/K` command line option for `Nmake`, but how could I pass this option if I have access only to `CMakeLists.txt` and `cmake.exe`? How can I pass arguments to the build tool in CMake's build tool mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass arguments to your build-tool after a `--`.
In your case it would be

```
cmake --build <buildDir> -- /K
```

Related documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake.1.html#build-tool-mode