# How to add command line options for mingw32-make from CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake, pdcurses

I'm trying to build a little cross-platform application using curses. To use curses cross-platform, I'm using the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52289096/12650706). It's almost working, except that on Windows (when running
`cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .. && cmake --build .` from my build folder), I get a bunch of errors about `PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX` not being defined. To fix this error, pdcurses says to set `INFOEX=N` in the `mingw32-make` call. I can compile it fine using `mingw32-make -f Makefile INFOEX=N`, but I can't figure out how to pass `INFOEX=N` from `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40693190/passing-arguments-in-cmakes-build-tool-mode ? You do `cmake --build . -- INFOEX=N` I think you could also use https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html

Answer (score 0):

A quick search through the repository indicates that the value is only used to add the `HAVE_NO_INFOEX` compiler definition. To allow the user to pass a configuration when configuring your project, you should add a cache variable which allows to pass the value when configuring the project (`cmake -D VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..`).

Adjusting the `CMakeLists.txt` file presented in the linked answer it could be done like this:

```
...

if (WIN32)
    # variable set to False unless provided by user
    set(PDCURSES_INFOEX_MISSING False CACHE BOOL "Does pdcurses need to define CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX?")
endif()

add_library(PDcurses
         # all of the sources
         ...
)

if (WIN32 AND PDCURSES_INFOEX_MISSING)
    target_compile_definitions(PDcurses PRIVATE HAVE_NO_INFOEX)
endif()

...
```

```
cmake -D PDCURSES_INFOEX_MISSING=True -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
```

Note: If you want to avoid requiring the user to make this choice and possibly getting it wrong you could also use `try_compile` to check, source including `windows.h` and using `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX` would compile or not for windows target system...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've managed to solve my problem a different way. While this probably does work, I realised that I was asking a bit of an XY Problem and instead just installed a slightly older version of pdcurses into MinGW in the 'Conventional' way.